# Searching in Oracle using like

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having an issue searching for `city like '%a_a%'`, which will return:

```
Ottawa
kanata
```

but it will not return: `santa barbara`
                    or: `barbaras`

I am having this issue using Oracle client 18c, managed or unmanaged.
The result is fine if I use Sql Developer from Oracle.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain he logic.  It is not clear what you are trying to filter on.

Comment: Select city from tablename where city like '%a_a%'; Trying to get all the cities that have that pattern. This is part of our test script and worked fine, until we upgraded to 18c, and trying to use the 18c odp.net driver......

Comment: How are you running this query using the ODP.NET driver? Can you provide enough code for us to replicate the problem?

Comment: Forget about the code, I am using Visual Studio 2019, and I am writing the sql directly in the query window, using Oracle managed driver.

Comment: Of course, `'%a_a%'` matches both *santa barbara* and *barbaras*. This problem is not caused by the DBMS.

Comment: I know, we have 12c, and the same sql returned the right results. The city column is Varchar2(40 byte)

Comment: I may sound stupid, but looks like is returning everything with exclusion of those that contains words with more than 1 character between a. For example if city contains Santa which contains 2 chars between first a and the second a, it will not be returned...

Comment: Are you saying that `'%a_a%'` does **not** match `Santa Barbara` while it should (and had in previous versions)?

Comment: Exactly, it is not returned by the search. If Ottawa is returned, if I changed to Attawa, it will not be returned...It may be a bug in the client, I don't know.

Comment: Are you sure you read the whole result-set?

Comment: In a `like` expression, `_` matches any single character, and `%` matches 0 or more characters. If you want to match cities that have an `a`, followed by zero or more characters, then another `a`, use `%a%a%`. If you want to match cities that have an `a`, followed by one or more characters, then another `a`, use `%a_%a%`. Here's documentation on the `like` condition (see the pattern-matching characters section): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm

Comment: I want all the cities that contains a followed by one character and then another a. What I want is clear. the result from sql developer, compared with the one from Visual Studio is different.

Comment: My bad, I missed the `ara` in `Santa Barbara`, you're right, `%a_a%` should match it. I think the problem is unlikely to be on the Oracle side here; I'm not able to replicate the issue in Oracle directly (PL/SQL Developer, to be precise).

Comment: If you just run this test query directly, what results do you get? `WITH test_data AS (
    SELECT 'Ottawa' AS city FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'kanata' AS city FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'gotham' AS city FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'santa barbara' AS city FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'metropolis' AS city FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'barbaras' AS city FROM dual
)

SELECT *
FROM test_data t
WHERE t.city LIKE ('%a_a%')`

Comment: @JoshEller: Ottawa kanata

Comment: Very strange... What about if you run this one? `WITH test_data AS ( SELECT 'gotham' AS city FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 'santa barbara' AS city FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 'barbaras' AS city FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 'Ottawa' AS city FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 'metropolis' AS city FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 'kanata' AS city FROM dual ) SELECT * FROM test_data t WHERE t.city LIKE ('%a_a%')`

Comment: @TheImpaler, I expect to return Santa barbara, and also barbaras. Don't you?

Comment: @JoshEller, the same result for the second sql, only Ottawa and Kanata.

Comment: Must be some kind of configuration of the Oracle Client (maybe the charset, collation?). Works well in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb08fc/1

Comment: Grasping at straws here, but is it possible anything there is used for comments (or something similar) in your Visual Studio environment, and isn't actually being sent to Oracle? Any way you can view the actual query Visual Studio is sending to your DB?